# How to properly retrieve .allObjects from a one to many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity, one-to-many

I have a Page that has many [Word]

```
class Page : NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var words: NSSet
```

I can then access that via :

```
let words = self.page.valueForKey("words")
```

My error comes from trying to cast it as `[Word]` :

```
for word in words!.allObjects as! [Word] {
```

Which returns :

```
error: <EXPR>:1:24: error: 'Word' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
words!.allObjects as! [Word]
                       ^~~~
Swift.Word:2:18: note: found this candidate
public typealias Word = Int
                 ^
found this candidate
```

**My theories**

I'm not too familiar with Swift/xCode errors yet. But is this trying to tell me that `Word` might be reserved elsewhere as a system object, and that I shouldn't have used it? My other theory was that maybe I'm not connecting my entities correctly..hence the `Word = Int`.

Here is my Word :

[image]

Here is my Page :

[image]

Any ideas what this error might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast a set to an array, or more precisely `NSSet` to `Array`. Also, you do not need the unsafe `valueForKey` when you have already properly subclassed.

```
let words = page.words as Set<Word>
```

You can enumerate that the same way as an array

```
for word in words { .... }
```

Comment: I thought `page.words` would have worked, but it returns : `error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'words'`. Just a wild shot here, but `words!.allObjects as Set<Word>` also returns `'Word' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`

Comment: That's because you did not cast `page` to `Page`.

Comment: ah that was it. Thanks so much. Your comment lead me to realizing I never connected the modelxcdID file with the class yet either. Thank you!